# How to add multiple feature files to Cucumber Runner Class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, tags, cucumber, sequence

I have 3 separate feature files and one `CucumberRunnerClass`. As per the sequence need to execute those are listed below:

Feature files : `Login.feature`, `NavigateCusMngt.feature`, `AddCustomer.feature`

However, when executing it goes to first execute the AddCustomer.feature, then Login.feature and finally 
NavigateCusMngt.feature.

Therefore, I observed `AddCustomer.feature` - skipped, system logged in then `NavigateCusMngt.feature` -gives errors.

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features/Login.feature", "src/test/resources/features/NavigateCusMngt.feature", "src/test/resources/features/AddCustomer.feature"},
    glue = {"phptravelstestcases"},
    tags = {"~@Ignore"},
    format = {
        "pretty",
        "html:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber-pretty/mercury-tours-RegisterUserTest",
        "json:target/cucumber-reports/json-reports/mercury-tours-RegisterUserTest.json",
        "rerun:target/cucumber-reports/rerun-reports/mercury-tours-RegisterUserTest.txt"
    }
)
```

please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The feature files are parsed alphabetically. I named mine with a starting letter in the right order, e.g.

```
A-Login.feature
B-NavigateCusMngt.feature
C-AddCustomer.feature
```

It's not ideal in the long run, but it is a workable solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to refactor the feature file names or is it only enough to change in the CucumberRunnerClass?

Comment: I have refactor the feature files as per the above mentioned answer.. but still failing the code.

Comment: @Samanthi is it not running the feature files in alphabetic order ?

Comment: @ou-ryperd, now its working as you explained. I haven't change feature file names for the tags added inside feature files before. Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: If instead of using letters to name your feature files, use numbers like this: 
001-Login.feature
002-NavigateCusMngt.feature
003-AddCustomer.feature

There will be moment you'll ran out of letters very fast. With 3 digits, you have a 1000 feature cushion.