# Examples are not executing in Cucumber,Web Page is not Initiated

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

```java
public class Login_Applicant_StepDef {
  
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @Given("^the URL$")
    public void the_URL() throws Throwable {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\SSMP\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\ChromeDriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get("http://localhost:4200/app-home");
    }
    
    @When("^Click on the Applicant Click here button$")
    public void click_on_the_Applicant_Click_here_button() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Candidate click here')]")).click();;
        //JavascriptExecutor jvs= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        //jvs.executeScript("argumnets[0].click()",emailBtn);
    }

    @Then("^user will navigate to login Page$")
    public void user_will_navigate_to_login_Page()  {
        
        driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:4200/candidate");
    }
    
    @Then("^enter valid \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void enter_valid_email(String email)  {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-0']")).sendKeys(email);
    }
    
    @Then("^click on Submit button$")
    public void click_on_Submit_button()  {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-button-wrapper']")).click();
    //JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    //js.executeScript("argumnets[0]..click()",loginBtn);
}
}
```

I've created two feature files and step definitions and right now 1 feature file, and step definition linked to TestRunner.How to link multiple FF and Stepdefs to the Test runner
also, Programme is not running with examples though I've added

[Applicant login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oeKZ.png)

[Test Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UaxV.png)

```
@App_login
Feature: Optevus Applicant Login Feature 

Scenario Outline: login with valid Credentials 
    Given the URL 
    When Click on the Applicant Click here button 
    Then user will navigate to login Page 
    Then enter valid "<email>"
    Then click on Submit button
    
Examples:
    | email                 |
    | kallursh@gmail.com    |
    | kallurishar@gmail.com |
```

[image: error]

Comment: Please replace screenshots with code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state which language you use, buty I'm assuming Java. I have answered some questions about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974985/does-not-have-a-matching-glue-code-in-groovy-cucumber/59980602#59980602) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60035876/how-to-add-multiple-feature-files-to-cucumber-runner-class/60036085#60036085). That should help you with multiple feature files. I'm not sure you can have multiple glue files/step definitions. But you can use your step definitions to invoke methods in other class files.

Comment: Selenium, with ava

Answer (score 0):

In @CucumberOptions, provide folder path where feature files resides in feature option and stepdef folder path in glue option.